# Runtime version policies are only supported in the managed workflow. In the bare workflow, runtime version needs to be set manually

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6anF.png)

Runtime version policies are only supported in the managed workflow. In the bare workflow, runtime version needs to be set manually. Error: update command failed.

anyone solve this error

eas update --branch preview --message "Updating the app"
i tried this code but not solve error